# What happens to Docusign envelope notifications when webhook fails?

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks

I am trying to implement Docusign in my company's system. I figured out how to use REST API and how to implement webhook to receive envelope event notifications. 
However I am wondering what happens when webhook returnes an error? Does Docusign resends notification after some amount of time? I can not find anything in the documentation.
Do I have to implement a pooling mechanism alongside with the webhook or there is a better way to manage this cases?

EDIT:

So here what i see in the failure journals:
[image]

One actually was republished but not the other one. Maybe error code makes the difference? The first one was a 5xx server side error and the other one 404 initially and 404 the second time too.

However DocuSign is not trying second attempt strait away but waits 24h?

Here is how I configure the envelope for notifications in C#:

```
envelope.EventNotification = new EventNotification()
{
    Url = _webhookUrl,
    RequireAcknowledgment = "true",
    LoggingEnabled = "true",
    IncludeEnvelopeVoidReason = "true",
    IncludeDocuments = "false",
    IncludeCertificateOfCompletion = "false",
    IncludeCertificateWithSoap = "false",
    IncludeDocumentFields = "false",
    IncludeHMAC = "false",
    IncludeSenderAccountAsCustomField = "false",
    IncludeTimeZone = "false",
    UseSoapInterface = "false",
    EnvelopeEvents = new List<EnvelopeEvent>() { new EnvelopeEvent("completed"), new EnvelopeEvent("declined"), new EnvelopeEvent("voided") },
    RecipientEvents = new List<RecipientEvent>() { new RecipientEvent(null, "Completed") }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Require Acknowledgement option is selected and a publication message fails to be acknowledged during the next 24 hours, the message goes back into the queue and the system will retry delivery after a successful acknowledgement is received.
This is for either no acknowledgment or a bad HTTP result. If a good HTTP results comes at anytime, the connect log is updated and the message is removed from the queue. 
 There is a maximum of ten retries.

Comment: Great that is exacly what I need. Is Docusign awaiting a specific response body or just an HTTP 200 code?

Comment: Just a good response code (not sure it's limited to 200, I think 201 is good too for example).
Please mark the question answered when you can. thanks!

Comment: Actually I still don't understand the logic.You said "the message goes back into the queue and the system will retry delivery after a successful acknowledgement is received". But if it does not receive successfull acknowledgment it wont try to send it again? So for exemple if the webhook is down it will get something like 404 for exemple and wont try to send the notification again? I would expect the opposite if no answer under 100ms or an HTTP error code then docusign try to resend?

Comment: I actually tried and the demo server didn't try to send new notification when my webhook sends some error code. Althoug I see error notification in Connect logs.

Comment: did you set the Connect to require acknowledgement? that option is off by default

Comment: Yes i set it on per envelope using envelope create in the api.

Comment: and does your server ignore the message or just sends an error? I wonder if the system would still use an error as "acknowledgement" if you can completely ignore - see what happens

Comment: I had 5xx cases and one 404 when messed up with ngrok. In all the cases i can see those notifications in the logs and the list of failures.

Comment: and there's no retry? are you sure?

Comment: Noticed this morning one of the envelopes actually got second attempt. But only 24h later and another one didn't have one. See picture in the initial question.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong, I'm revising my answer. It's 24 hours each time for a retry. But if the acknowledgement comes after a failure message - this is marked so and the retry is not needed.

Comment: No looks like you were right https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect It goes strate away into the queue then 24h according to the docs. But still for all of the failed notifications only one was resent and manual resending does not work. A bug?

Comment: I think the support article may be wrong, I was basing my answer on it, but I think it only is resent after 24 hours.